# VBA: How to use the Object Browser?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if this is the right place for my question, but: how do I use the object and the browser? I feel so inept when it comes to helping myself. I know I can google stuff (and I do, a lot), but I want to be able to use all resources at hand.

Let's take the border of a chart. Google helped me out once again and told me I can change it like this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

But how do I figure this out with the object browser? Let's say I type in "chart". I get a long list and after going through this, it's probably not how I figure it out because I'd have to know that I'm looking for `ChartArea`. Still, one question:

1. I found ChartArea for an entry where the Library is Excel, Class is Chart and Member is empty - does member being empty tell me something, is this something I should look for?
2. Anyway, moving on, I type in "border". I would've expected to find something in "class" that has something to do with chart. But I don't. So how am I supposed to know how to find what I'm looking for?
3. And while I'm at it, let me ask about the Microsoft help. I googled my way to the [Border.LineStyle property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border.linestyle). Obviously there's the code example that tells me about using it with Charts().ChartArea, but again, can I do this more methodically? On the left hand side, you can see LineStyle is a property of Border. From there, how do I move up one level? How do I see that Border is/can be a property of ChartArea?

Comment: If you click in the tree on the left-hand side of that page you will go to the reference for `Border`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border(object)  This is a more useful approach than the object browser.

Comment: I also prefer not to use the object browser.  Sometimes I just stub out subs and declare an object so I can dig through its properties with intellisense, the immediate window and the watch window.  Not as useful for looking 'up' the tree tho.

Comment: @TimWilliams yet the docs don't list the hidden members, so if all you're looking at is the docs, you can't know that `CharObject` (or a `Chart`) has a `Border` property, but the object browser lists it if you toggle "show hidden members" on.

Comment: @RyanB. I do that all the time too! But before doing that, you need to bring up the object browser and toggle "show hidden members" on, so *IntelliSense* shows everything there is to see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### TL;DR:

The `ChartArea.Border` property is hidden, you need to toggle "show hidden members" on in the Object Browser to see it.

Below is essentially everything there is to know about the Object Browser.

---

#### Library Filter & Search Box

The top part looks like this:

[image: libraries dropdown, search box]

That dropdown contains all referenced type libraries, identified by their programmatic name:

- `Excel`: the Excel type library, defines things like `Worksheet`, `Range`, etc.
- `Office`: a dependency of the Excel type library; defines things like `CommandBars`.
- `stdole`: another dependency; defines lower-level things like `StdFont` and `StdPicture`.
- `VBA`: the VBA standard library, defines things like `MsgBox`, `Collection`, etc.
- `VBAProject`: the type library of your compiled VBA project.

You'll want to use that dropdown to limit what you're looking at to the specific type library you're exploring - for example, `Excel`. Under the dropdown, there's a search box you can use to search for strings that appear in part of an identifier and populate the "search results" view - but you know that already.

#### Show Hidden Members

Right-click an empty area in the toolbar; select "Show hidden members" - now the object browser *and InteliSense* will be listing members that are otherwise hidden, and you'll quickly discover that the Excel type library is much larger than it seems.

[image: object browser context menu with "Show hidden members" toggled]

#### Edit Module/Member Descriptions

Navigate to your `VBAProject` library, and find one of your modules in the left pane; the right pane will be listing the members of that module. Right-click either the module or one of its members, and select "Properties" - the "Member Options" dialog pops up and lets you enter a description:

[image: Member Options dialog]

Module and member descriptions show up in the bottom pane when they exist:

[image: Module description displayed in the bottom pane]

If you exported that module, you would see that it now has a hidden `VB_Description` attribute with a string value that matches what you entered for a description.

If you're using [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck), you can use special comments ("annotations") to control these hidden attributes, too:

```
'@ModuleDescription("This module contains some boring recorded macros.")
Option Explicit

'@Description("Does something...")
Public Sub Macro1()
    '...
End Sub
```

Rubberduck annotations can also [control/synchronize other hidden attributes](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations) that the *Object Browser* isn't exposing, but I digress.

---

The left pane ("classes") displays all the types in the selected library; the right pane lists the members of the selected type, grouped by kind (properties, methods, events, etc.); what you must keep in mind, is that no matter how many members are named the same as types/classes/interfaces, a member is a member, not a type.

Taking this expression:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

We can start with finding what object type the `Sheets` member call belongs to. If we filter for the `Excel` library and search for `Sheets`, we find 2 interesting results where a member is named `Sheets`:

- `Application.Sheets`
- `Workbook.Sheets`

This means unless that line of code is in the code-behind of `ThisWorkbook`, what we're calling can't be `Workbook.Sheets` - but we're not qualifying it with `Application` either! If we reveal hidden members, we discover a hidden `Global` class and a `_Global` interface that both expose a `Sheets` member! From there we can infer that the Excel object model is "redirecting" our unqualified `Sheets` call to the `Application` object, which looks like it's giving us the `Sheets` member of whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is. In any case, the relationship between `_Global` and `Global` is confusing: we select `_Global.Sheets` and the bottom panel tells us we're looking at a member of `Excel.Global`:

[image: _Global.Sheets]

Notice the property doesn't have any parameters: it simply yields a reference to a `Sheets` object. So we look at the returned `Sheets` type - either by clicking the hyperlink in the bottom panel, or by browsing the left panel to find the `Sheets` collection type (which conveniently happens to have the same name as the `Sheets` property of the `Global`, `Application`, and `Workbook` classes).

Note that the `Workbook.Worksheets` property also yields a `Sheets` collection object.

Like all other collection classes, the `Sheets` class has a *default member*, and this one is hidden, it's named `_Default`, and it returns an `Object`. We can guess that the property is forwarding the call to the `Item` indexer, because collection classes normally expose a way to access their items by index or by name/key (by convention it's named `Item` but sometimes it's something else, like `Recordset.Fields`)... but now that property also returns an `Object`.

> ***Default Members***
>   Classes in VBA can have a member (only one!) that can be implicitly invoked when the object is coerced into a value. This member has a hidden `VB_UserMemId` attribute with a value of `0`, and the object browser identifies it with a blue/cyan dot on the member's icon. That's how `Application.Name` gets output when you write `Debug.Print Application`; that's also how you get `Range.Value` when you `Let`-coerce a `Range` object into a `Variant` or any other non-object type without using the `Set` keyword... and it's why the `Set` keyword is required when assigning object references: without it the compiler wouldn't have a way to tell whether you mean to assign the object itself or its default member value... which can very well be another object reference.
>   In general, it's best to avoid implicit default member calls and be explicit, so that the code *says what it does, and does what it says*.

At this point we're stumped, just like the compiler is: every further member call on that line of code is only resolvable at run-time - it's all late-bound, and when you type it you get no *IntelliSense*, no autocompletion, no compile-time validation: even `Option Explicit` can't save you from a typo, and if you make one you'll know because VBA will throw error 438 "I can't find that member" at you.

`Sheets._Default` returns an `Object`: not all sheets are `Worksheet` objects - a `Chart` could be a sheet as well! That's why we usually prefer to use the `Workbook.Worksheets` property instead, so that we're certain to get a `Worksheet` object. Right? "Sheet1" is a `Worksheet`, we know as much!

We could restore early binding by declaring a `Worksheet` variable:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
sheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

So we browse to the `Worksheet` type in the left pane, find its `ChartObjects` method (it's a `Function`), which also returns an `Object`. Looks like naming properties after their type is a common convention in the Excel type library - there's a `ChartObjects` object collection in the left pane, and we can probably assume its items are `ChartObject` objects; so we find the `ChartObject` class again in the left pane, and see that it has a `Chart` property that returns a `Chart` object:

[image: Excel.ChartObject class members]

At this point we can restore early binding further down the chain of member calls, by extracting another variable:

```
Dim targetChartObj As ChartObject
Set targetChartObj = sheet.ChartObjects(1)
targetChartObj.Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

The `ChartArea` property yields a `ChartArea` object, so we find the `ChartArea` class in the left panel, ...and see that it has a *hidden* `Border` property!

[image: Excel.ChartArea.Border is hidden!]

The `ChartArea.Border` property returns a `Border` object, which again we find in the left panel to see that it has a `LineStyle` property... of type `Variant`. How are we supposed to know `xlContinuous` is even a thing then? Is there no hope?

At this point we could google up `Border.LineStyle` and see if the docs give us a clue about the legal values, ...or we could try to search for `LineStyle` in the search box...

[image: searching for LineStyle turns up the XlLineStyle enum]

...and see that there's an `XlLineStyle` enum with a member named `xlContinuous`, alongside all other constants defined under that enum. A quick online search brings up the official docs and confirms that [Border.LineStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border.linestyle) wants an `XlLineStyle` enum value!

Now, this was moving left-to-right. Going right-to-left, you can work your way up by leveraging the search box; searching for "Border" with hidden members visible, lists the `ChartArea.Border` member in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

1. When member is empty then the object is a `Class`
2. Many objects can have a border. I don't see a border property on either `Chart` or `ChartArea`. This makes it hard to tell what objects have a border. If you can configure a border in the GUI that's a good indicator that you can do it in code.
3. This is the top of the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model

I use the link I gave in A3. I never use the object viewer inside excel. The microsoft documentation doesn't always have everything you need. You will find obscure webpages that have undocumented features. How do people learn this arcane art? Either trial and error, or it's passed down from one wizard to the next.