# How to calculated Date from absolute hour?

Tags: excel, vba

How to calculate absolute hour in VBA excel. I have c# code just need help transforming into VBA Excel. I am missing DateTime library in VBA.
I am trying using standard 2015 year transform absolute hour[1-8760] from simulation hour to Date for easier identification and results interpretations.

```
public static string FromHourToDateString(int HourIndex)
{
   DateTime aDateTime = new DateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(HourIndex).Ticks + new DateTime(2015, 1, 1).Ticks);
   return aDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy@HH:mm");
}
```

Comment: There's no `DateTime` library in C# either; `DateTime` is a `struct` defined in the `System` namespace. In VBA you have the `VBA.DateTime` module, exposing a number of functions including `Date`, `DateAdd`, `DateDiff`, `DateValue`, `TimeValue`, `TimeSerial`, and several others. Hit F2 in the VBE to bring up the [Object Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122859/1188513) and dig everything you need.

Comment: That said, not sure what that function is trying to achieve with `Ticks`.

Comment: example, HourIndex=`3230` returns `15-05-2015@14:00`. I can not get `TimeSpan` in VBA

Comment: I come manage to get answer I want to post to help other but seems my account will be blocked from answering ... ? what is going on here.... does it mean is better not share if I come across answer?

Comment: You're not blocked from answering, SO is just prompting whether you really mean to answer your own question. Possible that there's a wait period though.

Comment: From what I gather you want to get the date for 2015-01-01 (trivial), then divide HourIndex by 24 and add that, then add the remainder. I still don't see why you would need to get ticks involved in the C# solution though.

Answer (score 0):

What are your expected result? The current time and date?

If so you may simply use

```
Now()
```

This returns dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm from your system date/time.

Include it in another statement, for instance

```
    Dim rng, rng2 as range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    rng = Now()
```

To get the hours here, a simple variant could be

```
     rng2 = Right(rng, 5)
```

There is of course other ways without writing to sheet, try storing in a variable for example. However this illustrates the point.. Handling the date as a string let's you edit it with left/right functions etc.

Comment: I am trying using standard 2015 year transform hour from simulation to Date for easier identification and results interpretations. Thanks for your solution but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I see, I'm not too familiar with that method unfortunately.