# Change arrow color based on its label or value

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the color of an arrow based on its label (converted to integer); say if the value of the arrow is <50; then change the color of the arrow to green?

I encountered run-time error 438:

> Object doesn't support this property or method (Line 3).

```
Sub ArrowColour()
Dim nsize As Integer
nsize = CInt(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Left Arrow 1")).Value)
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Left Arrow 1")).Fill
    If nsize < 50 Then
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Shapes.Range` returns a `ShapeRange`, which isn't a `Range` object / doesn't have a `Value` property. See [how to use the object browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122859/1188513) for tips on figuring out what returns what.

Answer (score 2):

Shapes don't have a `Value` property.

Try this:

```
Sub ArrowColour()     
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Left Arrow 1")
        .ForeColor.RGB = IIf(CInt(.TextFrame.Characters.Text)<50, _
                             RGB(0, 176, 80), RGB(255, 0, 0))    
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sTemp As String
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("RightArrow")
    sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    If CInt(sTemp) > 400 Then
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
    End Sub
```